# VS 2010 build undoes edits to xml file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My environment: VS 2010 Pro, .NET 4, C#, Silverlight 4, ASP.NET, Win2008 Server R2, IIS 7.5

I have a VS solution that contains a Silverlight project hosted in an ASP.NET project. The ASP.NET project includes a conf folder with .xml files that are used for configuration via WebClient class. A WCF service embedded in the ASP.NET project. The application is configured as an ASP.NET application in IIS.

I want to be able to edit the configuration files inside and outside of VS and have the edits stick. I edit the .xml file to change the WCF endpoint. When i build the solution in VS, it succeeds but something outside VS changes the xml back to previous state, discarding the edits. This happens with other settings in the .xml file as well. The problem occurred earlier when I was using Casini too.

If the .xml file is open in VS, then I get the message "This file has been modified outside of the source editor. Do you want to reload it?" If the .xml file is not open in VS, then I don't get the message. Having the files as part or not part of the VS solution doesn't seem to make a difference.

This might be due to some setting in Win2008 R2 or IIS 7, since I have not run into this problem on other windows platforms.

This problem might be similar to the post at...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040555/how-can-i-tell-visual-studio-2010-to-stop-overriding-my-xml-edits

Comment: Are the XML files under source control?

Comment: Currently under SVN, but this started happening before I put them under source control

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, my own fault, due to a mis-configuration of a VS project contained in the solution.

Earlier I had created a post-build event in VS that copied another version of the xml config file in a different VS project, overwriting the one I was trying to edit (duh...). Totally forgot about it. Fixed the problem by simply eliminating it

Comment: You should describe what the misconfiguration was (and the way to correct it), for the benefit of people finding this answer in the future.

Comment: Earlier I had created a post-build event in VS that copied another version of the xml config file in a different VS project, overwriting the one I was trying to edit (duh...). Totally forgot about it. Fixed the problem by simply eliminating it.

Comment: Thanks for updating the info. I've moved the comment into the answer you posted. You may want to delete the comment (in case you don't know, you can do so by moving the mouse to the right of the timestamp on your comment, and an `x` will appear. Clicking that deletes the comment.)